# List volumes missing specific tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, boto, jmespath

I am trying to list Volumes from the AWS CLI that is missing a specific tag key. While I can list volumes missing a specific key with below command.

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes  --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `MakeSnapshot`].Value)] | [].[VolumeId]' --output text
```

Looking for logical OR operation inside the query statement by which I can list all the Volumes missing either of two keys something similar to this.

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes  --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `MakeSnapshot|MakeDevSnapshot`].Value)] | [].[VolumeId]' --output text
```

Is it possible to perform such logical AND/OR operations within the query/James Path search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JMESPath Specification for OR expressions uses `||`. Reference [here](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#or-expressions)

Try,

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes  --query 'Volumes[?!not_null(Tags[?Key == `MakeSnapshot || MakeDevSnapshot`].Value)] | [].[VolumeId]' --output text
```